# add custom menu in woocommerce dashboard

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

[image] I have added custom menu just as in image above . But i am unable to open the pages. They are showing 404 page not found.

Comment: [Wordpress Menu User Guide](https://codex.wordpress.org/WordPress_Menu_User_Guide)

Comment: Questions regarding 3rd-party products require deeply intimate and niche knowledge about the product in question in order to provide good answers. As a result, they are off-topic here, and would be best addressed in the product's official support channels, or another community platform which caters to users of the product.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following to create a sub menu under woocommerce.
Please use the following for reference.
https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_submenu_page/

```
 add_action('admin_menu', 'testing_submenu_page');

function testing_submenu_page() {
    add_submenu_page( 'woocommerce', 'sub menu', 'sub menu', 'manage_options', 'woo-subpage-test', 'test_callback' );
}

function test_callback() {

    echo '<div class="wrap"><div id="icon-tools" class="icon32"></div>';
        echo '<h2> Sub menu test page</h2>';
    echo '</div>';

}
```

Example what the results will look like:

[image]

Comment: where should i implement this code.? In which file,??

Comment: You can create a new plugin OR you can even add this to your themes function.php file. I just tested and its working.

Comment: Dean.I just paste this code on my functions.php. But nothing happen.

Comment: osvin. please note that you have to put the code in the function file of the **active theme**.

Comment: yes.it happens. But I also want it on when i click on "MY ACCOUNT" tab, I want 'sub-menu' on front-end.

Comment: Can somebody help me with that..???

Answer (score 0):

Ok. I found the page. It is wc-account-functions.php. We can add custom menus from here. But still i am unable to open that pages. link is showing 404.